# What is the good way to lint SharedWorker code using eslint inside Vue application that runs on Vite

Tags: vuejs3, eslint, vite, shared-worker

I have a standard Vue 3/Vite application scaffolded using

```
npm create vue
```

I am using eslint in the project and I want to add a SharedWorker to my app. I have created `worker.js` file inside the project, where `onconnect` handler is defined. With that setup I get eslint error message:

```
'onconnect' is not defined. eslint(no-undef)
```

How can I avoid this error without silencing it and make sure `worker.js` is linted properly?

Comment: Please include the relevant code that generates the error in your question.  We can't tell from just your description whether or not the error is warranted, or what should be changed to prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround is:

1. in your `tsconfig.app.json` add to `compilerOptions.lib`

```
{
  /* other stufs */
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "DOM", /* for document.* */
      "WebWorker", /* for *WorkerGlobalScope */
    ]
  }
}
```

2. Then in your `worker.ts|.js` add `declare const self: SharedWorkerGlobalScope;` at the top of your file
3. to use `onconnect`add `self` before like this

```js
self.onconnect = function(event) {
    const port = event.ports[0];
    console.log(port)

    port.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log('Received message in SharedWorker:', e.data);
        // Process the received string data here
    };
};
```